# how can I add a scroll down panel effect on my squarespace website?

Tags: css, web, scroll, effect, squarespace

sorry for the title, I genuinely don't know what the effect is called. Basically when the title appears on a clear panel and you have to scroll down to reveal the rest of the page.  I linked it here to illustrate my request: https://www.piariverola.com/m-le-monde-le-mexique-solaire-et-magntique

Is there a specific CSS code I need to add to my own squarespace ? please I'm desperate !

I'm relatively knew to website building, I just want a nice photography portfolio similar to the one I linked. I tried going on the page I just linked and right clicked on my mac to inspect the htlm and css, I found the elements but i'm not sure how to add them to "custom css" ON SQUARESPACE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.